# not so good questions with well researched answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

A question if I may.

What is the policy here about deletion of not so good questions that may have good, well researched answers attached?  Are they deleted eventually?

Well researched answers often take considerable amount of time to research/write and would certainly be a contribution to the site.  Are these lost if the not so good question is eventually deleted?

Would it be prudent for the answerer to submit an edit to the question in order to improve on it, hence not close it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Questions that look like senseless, but with sensible answers](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4634/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, such questions shouldn't be answered in the first place. Instead, flag for closure, and leave a comment on how it can be improved. If the question is improved, it can be reopened.

> What is the policy here about deletion of not so good questions that may have good, well researched answers attached?

They get closed, but that's it.

> Are they deleted eventually?

Nope. See Emilio's answer.

> Would it be prudent for the answerer to submit an edit to the question in order to improve on it, hence not close it?

In some cases, it's fine to edit a closed (or an about-to-be-closed) question to change it to something more constructive so that it matches the answer.

Comment: It's always prudent to edit questions to improve them whenever they can be improved. That's how this is supposed to work :)

Comment: @tpg2114 Of course, however drastic edits in an attempt to save a question -- not always a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

There is a specific policy *against* deleting questions that have good answers. Have a look at [the 10k privileges page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools): from the Deleting Posts section,

> #### When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check that there are **no good answers**; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

On the e-ground it is of course always more or less of a judgement call on the part of the community, but there need to be 3 or more 10k users that vote deletion, or a moderator.

If you feel that a question was deleted wrongly, bring it up in meta. (This is of course a tricky matter because you usually can't see them. 10k users can, though, so anything obviously wrong will eventually get picked up on.)